# YearMonth field stored on mongodb cannot be parsed back to object field

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, mongodb-java

Background: My application is built on top of **Spring Data REST** and **MongoDB Repositories**.

Consider this simple Java domain object with a `YearMonth` field:

```
@Getter @Setter
public class Console {
    @Id private String id;
    private String name;
    private YearMonth releaseMonth;
    private Vendor vendor;
}
```

And this domain object is made available for persistence by a MongoRepository implementation:

```
public interface ConsoleRepository extends MongoRepository<Console, String> {
    Console findByName(@Param("name") String name);
}
```

When exposing a REST Controller (automatically by Data REST) to manage this domain object, I've added `jackson-datatype-jsr310` gradle dependency in order to parse YearMonth JSON values (e.g.: "2016-04") into this field by jackson:

```
compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:2.6.1'
```

When POST'ing to this endpoint, the YearMonth value contained on the JSON document is correctly parsed into a YearMonth field and the whole object is stored as a document on MongoDB successfully. Looking up this document on mongo proves that:

```
> db.console.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("575f837ca75df1fc7e5f4f96"),
  "_class" : "xxx.yyy.Console",
  "name" : "Console 1",
  "releaseMonth" : { "year" : 1988, "month" : 10 },
  "vendor" : "VENDOR_1" }
```

However, when I try to GET that resource from the REST controller, MongoDB client fails to bind this YearMonth value into the Java object:

```
GET localhost:8080/consoles
```

Response:

```
{
  "timestamp": 1465954648903,
  "status": 500,
  "error": "Internal Server Error",
  "exception": "org.springframework.data.mapping.model.MappingException",
  "message": "No property null found on entity class java.time.YearMonth to bind constructor parameter to!",
  "path": "/consoles"
}
```

I'd assume MongoDB Java client lacks built-in support for Java 8's YearMonth values, but since it is being able to save them, that seems to be ruled out. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to parse this object by creating a [Custom Converter](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongo.custom-converters.reader):

```
@Component
public class DBObjectToYearMonthConverter implements Converter<DBObject, YearMonth> {
    @Override
    public YearMonth convert(DBObject source) {
        return YearMonth.of(
            (int) source.get("year"),
            (int) source.get("month")
        );
    }
}
```

And setting up a CustomConversions @Bean on Application class:

```
@Bean
public CustomConversions getCustomConversions() {
    return new CustomConversions(Arrays.asList(
        new DBObjectToYearMonthConverter()
    ));
}
```

Other options are welcome.

Comment: I tried the same and it didn't work so I look at the date and realised I'm using newer version and it's reactive and I'm even using Kotlin. Problem was simple, using DBObject instead of org.bson.Document. After correcting the type the converter worked. I just wanted to leave this here in case anyone made this kind of converter earlier and wanted to switch to new version.